# When I am trying to use reloaded friend function by pointer from inherited class, it uses function from base class

Tags: c++, class, pointers, inheritance

I am bringing my apologies for my crooked English in advance (If there any obvious mistakes , I'd be pleased to know about them)
My problem is that cannot use overloaded function from inherited class.
I create array of pointers to Base class and during the program create objects, it can be  base class or inherited. When it comes to use the overloaded function (operator<<) , it constantly uses the option for base class, but when I create two separate object(Base class, Inherited class from base class), overloaded operator works perfectly well. What direction should I dig in?
There is the Code

```
#include <iostream>
#include "port.hpp"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    port *p_port[2];
    p_port[0] = new VintagePort("BrandONe", 10, "NickName", 19978);
    p_port[1] = new port("BrandNameTwo","StyleTwo",1);
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        cout << *p_port[i] << endl;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        delete p_port[i];
    
    cout << endl;
    port p("BrandNameTwo","Style",2);
    VintagePort vp("BrandName",19,"NickName",1982);
    cout << p << endl;
    cout << vp << endl;
}
```

```
#ifndef PORT_HPP_
#define PORT_HPP_
#include <iostream>
class port
{
private:
    char *brand;
    char style[20];
    int bottles;

public:
    port(const char *br = "none", const char *st = "none", int b = 0);
    port(const port &p);
    virtual ~port() { delete[] brand; }
    port &operator=(const port &p);
    port &operator+=(int b);
    port &operator-=(int b);
    int BottleCount() const { return bottles; }
    virtual void Show() const;
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const port &p);
};
class VintagePort : public port
{
private:
    char *nickname;
    int year;

public:
    VintagePort();
    VintagePort(const char *br, int b, const char *nn, int y);
    VintagePort(const VintagePort &vp);
    ~VintagePort() { delete[] nickname; }
    VintagePort &operator=(const VintagePort &vp);
    void Show() const;
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const VintagePort &vp);
};

#endif
```

```
#include "port.hpp"
using std::ostream;
port::port(const char *br, const char *st, int b)
{
    brand = new char[strlen(br) + 1];
    strcpy(brand, br);
    strcpy(style, st);
    bottles = b;
}
port::port(const port &p)
{
    brand = new char[strlen(p.brand) + 1];
    strcpy(brand, p.brand);
    strcpy(style, p.style);
    bottles = p.bottles;
}
port &port::operator=(const port &p)
{
    if (this == &p)
        return *this;
    delete[] brand;
    brand = new char[strlen(p.brand) + 1];
    strcpy(brand, p.brand);
    strcpy(style, p.style);
    bottles = p.bottles;
    return *this;
}
port &port::operator+=(int b)
{
    bottles += b;
    return *this;
}
port &port::operator-=(int b)
{
    bottles -= b;
    return *this;
}
void port::Show() const
{
    std::cout << "Brand: " << brand;
    std::cout << "\nKind: " << style;
    std::cout << "\nBottles: " << bottles << std::endl;
}
ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, const port &p)
{
    out << p.brand << ", " << p.style << ", "
        << p.bottles << std::endl;
    return out;
}
VintagePort::VintagePort()
{
    nickname = nullptr;
    year = 0;
}
VintagePort::VintagePort(const char *br, int b, const char *nn, int y)
    : port(br, "vintage", b)
{
    year = y;
    nickname = new char[strlen(nn) + 1];
    strcpy(nickname, nn);
}
VintagePort::VintagePort(const VintagePort &vp) : port(vp)
{
    nickname = new char[strlen(vp.nickname) + 1];
    strcpy(nickname, vp.nickname);
    year = vp.year;
}
VintagePort &VintagePort::operator=(const VintagePort &vp)
{
    if (this == &vp)
        return *this;
    port::operator=(vp);
    delete[] nickname;
    nickname = new char[strlen(vp.nickname) + 1];
    strcpy(nickname, vp.nickname);
    year = vp.year;
    return *this;
}
void VintagePort::Show() const
{
    std::cout << "\nNickname: " << nickname << std::endl;
    port::Show();
}
ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, const VintagePort &vp)
{
    out << vp.nickname << ", ";
    // operator<<(os, (const port &)vp);
    operator<<(out, (const port &)vp);
    return out;
}
```

Here outcome of program

```
BrandONe, vintage, 10

BrandNameTwo, StyleTwo, 1


BrandNameTwo, Style, 2

NickName, BrandName, vintage, 19
```

I'm rather new here, sorry, if I made sth wrong

Comment: "When it comes to use the overloaded function,..." which function do you mean? What output did you expect instead?

Comment: How do you expect to be able to use an "overloaded function", the << overload, without the benefit of it being virtual? You have a virtual class method already defined, so I presume that you understand what they are, and how they work. So what, exactly, is unclear about the reason for the << overload's behavior, here, and how to fix it? Did you [try explaining how your << overload is supposed to work, to your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)?

Comment: @ 463035818_is_not_a_number, sorry for being unclear, overload function is operator<<,
 I presume, that using  function 
ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, const port &p) 
 and
 ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, const VintagePort &vp) 
would make the program distinct two different classes, and therefore use different output,in fact I get different output, but only when I call them without using pointers,  when it comes to use arr port *p_port[2], the program uses one variant of function for all the elements, did I make myself clear? ;) If not, please, tell me what's wrong

Comment: please read about [mcve]. I think you could remove most of the posted code while still reproducing the issue

Comment: @ Sam Varshavchik, as far as I know, friend function can't be virtual, therefore i made operator<< overloaded.
The reason I did this that I presumed  compiler would distinct two different classes and therefore use different variant of function, but it didn't.
Of course, I will review my code and try explaining the concept to my rubber duck, but now I am a little at sea, so I decided to ask there, sorry, if I am being unclear, I find it uneasy to explain myself clear in English

Comment: `p_port[0]` has static type `port` and dynamic type `VintagePort`. overloads use static type. dynamic type would be with `virtual` methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overloading and overriding are very different things.

Overloads are selected at compile time, using the static type.
Since the type of the array elements is `port*`, the `port&` overload is selected.

If you want a "dynamic" `operator<<`, create one that accepts the base class and just dispatches to a virtual member function which you can override.

Example:

```
class port
{
    // ...
public:
    virtual std::ostream& print(std::ostream* os) const
    {
        out << brand << ", " << style << ", "
            << bottles << std::endl;
        return out;
    }
    
};


std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const port& p)
{
    return p.print(os);
}

class VintagePort : public port
{
    // ...
public:
    std::ostream& print(std::ostream& out) const override
    {
        out << vp.nickname << ", ";
        return port::print(out);
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you, now I understand where something went wrong!